# Editing Answers in This Site

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to leave corrections for answers in the comments regarding grammar on this site? It bothers me that suggested edits have disappeared here. It would be nice to have those. After all, we are all on an *English* website, whether it's support-oriented or not.

PS: If anyone cares, and nobody does, I edit pretty much every answer I can get to on Quora. Suggestions are fun.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "suggested edits have disappeared here" and "it would be nice to have those"? You want to be able to view suggested edits that were deemed as not beneficial by the community? (not a suggestive comment, genuinely curious)

Comment: Your suggested edit is still here; you just need to [know where to look](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/238136).

Comment: @J.R. I don't know where this attitude came from, but allow me to clarify myself. "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." That's a policy I don't why is in place. I was just asking if leaving a list of suggestions in the comments was allowed. Sheesh!

Comment: @SebastianPojman probably because meta is mostly for discussion, where users frequently post their own opinions regarding several issues in order to reach a community consensus. If other users edit these posts, it could mean losing key information. So, unless a meta post is marked _community wiki_, or unless you have a certain reputation and the associated new privileges, you cannot make changes to other users' meta posts.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you be extremely selective in editing, or even making suggested edits, to posts here. Your suggested edits to the post linked to in JR's comment were rightly rejected. Your preference of using *which/that* is not as important as the OP's preference. Also, inserting *Old* changed the meaning of what the OP wrote.

Comment: Okay then, I will.

Comment: *"Is it allowed to leave corrections for answers in the comments?"*  Yes, in all SE sites that I've participated in, including ELU and ELU Meta, when the software doesn't permit one to propose an edit in a more direct way, it is fine to provide a polite, respectful suggestion that would improve the post, in the form of a comment below the post.

Answer (score 9):

Depends.

You can suggest edits to posts on the main ELU site, which will be approved or rejected by users with higher reputation.

Or, once you've crossed a certain reputation (2000, on this site), the system grants you extra privileges, one of which is that you'll be able to make edits to any post you see, and it will be approved instantly without peer review.

That's why we have these things like reputation and badges and stuff.

Regarding leaving comments with suggestions, it's actually the very reason we have the comments section.

Leave constructive criticism and suggestions for improvement wherever you find mistakes, remember to be nice, and avoid posting comments targeting the user instead of their post.

Regarding the privileges to suggest edits or make instant edits on meta, the rules may be a bit different, and probably because meta is mostly for discussion, where users frequently post their own opinions regarding several issues in order to reach a community consensus, and if other users edit these posts, it could mean losing key information. So, unless a meta post is marked *community wiki*, or unless you have a certain reputation and the associated new privileges, you cannot make changes to other users' meta posts.

All the rules and FAQs are available in [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).